# Create a dynamic custom fields using salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am new to salesforce. I have created a custom fields in salesforce both on custom and in standard object. But is it possible to create a custom fields dynamically? P

Please provide me pointer if you can.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_calls_intro.htm

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by 'dynamically'? Yes there is Metadata API that allows your code to modify fields etc. However, typically you are advised against schema modification at runtime.